# Swift - Firebase - applicationReceivedRemoteMessage Conflict

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Using Swift 2.3 - Firebase 4

|*| If I try to implement this method its says :

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

> Objective-C method 'applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:' provided by method 'applicationReceivedRemoteMessage' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(received:)' in protocol 'MessagingDelegate'

Kindly let me know which is the new correct method

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
     // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
     FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
     // handle your message
   }
```

reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

Answer (score 0):

- Implement following delegate methods in your AppDelegate.swift file:

  ```
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
     print("Remote message received for this app")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {       
     print("This \(userInfo)")
     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
  }
  ```